# logging fails to configure some imported modules (including imports) (python logging)

Tags: python, logging

I want to print all logging messages from all imported modules. Certain imported modules are not logging.

Note that all the files in the libraries I care about have calls
`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` at the top.

Sorry if this is an easy problem. I've looked through a lot of posts without success.

I observe that the loggers for some modules are not being updated by the call to basicConfig

```py
import logging
import local_util   # a local util file
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration

for n in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    print(logging.getLogger(n))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s::%(module)s::%(funcName)s() %(message)s")
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

for n in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    print(logging.getLogger(n))
```

In the first call to `print(logging.getLogger(n))` almost all loggers are set with level WARNING.

In the second call, most loggers are set to DEBUG (including the one for local_util), except for the transformers library which all remain at level WARNING.

I can get transformers messages to print if I manually cycle through all loggers and reset their levels. Even if I use `force=True` in the call to basicConfig, the loggers for the transformers library do not get updated.

Comment: Presumably `transformers` is setting up logging the way it wants to - have you looked at the source code? If it is then you’ll have to override it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`basicConfig` means to affect the root logger. If other child loggers don't set their level (which is default to `NOTSET`), they use the level of the root logger.

So if `transformers` has set a `WARNING` level on its own, it won't use `DEBUG` level of root.

You can set its level directly as the following:

```py
transformers_logger = logging.getLogger('transformers')
transformers_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Is there some way to bulk-set all of the loggers? Or maybe transformers has a transformer root logger that I could set that would then set all the transformers children loggers?